# How physical it is to change structure in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

If I am storing employee data in firebase which has 3 fields and in future if I want add or remove a field then how physical it is in firebase ? and how can I do it?

I want to use Firebase for one of my iOS project(Swift 4) which I am going to start working on soon so I want to clear the above mentioned concern.

Comment: You need to provide some details about your work.

Comment: Firebase is a run time json file you don't need to make predefined sql table structure here. Whenever you need to add any key just do it like you do in `Dictionary` or `Array` and each node can have different data structure. So in one line save whatever you want to save in `Dictionary`, `Array`, `Number`, `Bool`, and `String` format.

Comment: The Firebase documentation getting started guides are a pretty good starting point. Check out [Reading and Writing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Comment: @TheTiger Thank for your answer, it is short and simple. Actually was confused because I was still looking at Firebase from traditional Table view perspective.

Comment: @jay Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While Lance's answer works - here's a simple alternative. Assume you want to remove an age 'field' from Firebase. Given a structrue

```
employees
  employee_0
    name: "Steve"
    age: "42"
  employee_1
    name: "Hank"
    age: "37"
```

if you want to remove the age node from all employee nodes, this will do it

```
let employeesRef = Database.database().reference().child("employees")
employeesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let key = snapshot.key
    let refToRemove = employeesRef.child(key).child("age")
    refToRemove.removeValue()
})
```

Adding a field (child node) is even simpler as child node values cannot be nil so when you write the data, it's added to the node

```
employeesRef.child(employee_key).child("favorite_food").setValue("pizza")
```

will add a *favorite food* node with a value of *pizza* to an employee node.

Note that there are no 'fields' in Firebase, only parent and child nodes which are key: value pairs.

Comment: it’s a good answer, but no one knows if the OP can even understand what you wrote (or what I did). Yours is simpler for the situation but harder to understand if you’ve never used FB before. But this is the OP’s fault for not adding code to begin with.

Comment: @jay Thank you for detailed explanation with code. I question was only at concept level as I was looking at Firebase from transition database Table perspective. Thank you so much once again!

Comment: @LanceSamaria Thank you for your input Lance however I have basic understanding of Firebase coding! You can find the explanation in above code why I didn't include code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Jay’s answer is the better way to accomplish what you are asking but this is an alternative. If your a beginner this might be easier to understand and start with. As you advance use Jay’s code.

Seems like you want to do something like this.

Your database structure in Firebase is:

```
root
  |
  @-012345 // eg. employeeId
       |-"firstName": "Hello"
       |-"lastName": "World"
       |-"age": "25"
```

You want to add or remove a field there are several ways to do it but this way it's easy. All you have to to is keep track of the original values then add those plus the new values to a `Dictionary` and exclude whatever you don't want to send to Firebase using the `.setValue()` method :

```
// class properties
let rootRef: DatabaseReference? = Database.database().reference()
let employedID = "012345"
let firstName = "Hello" // original value you want to keep
let lastName = "World" // original value you want to keep
let age = "25" // original value you want to REMOVE
lat gender = "female" // NEW value you want ADDED

// press the button to send the write the values to Firebase
@IBAction fileprivate func updateEmployeeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // add the values to a dictionary
    let dict = [String:Any]()
    dict.(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    dict.(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
    dict.(gender, forKey: "gender")

    let employeeIdRef = rootRef?.child(employedID)
    employeeIdRef?.setValue(dict) // call Firebase's .setValue method and pass the dict as an argument
}
```

Your database structure will now look like this:

```
root
  |
  @-012345
       |-"firstName": "Hello"
       |-"lastName": "World"
       |-"gender": "female"
```

Notice the way I’m proposing complete overwrites what was at that node but Jay’s way keeps what was there but still gets you the changes you want to make.

Comment: This seems overly complex and I think the OP wanted to remove nodes from all employees nodes, not just one. Also, this answer completely overwrites an existing node with new data - while functionally it works, its not necessary if you're just adding a child node.

Comment: I know it over writes it. The OP’s question didn’t add any code and wasn’t very clear so it’s up to us to interpret what he says. You read it as he wanted to do it for different employees but I read it as he just wanted to know if it can get done. It’s only 6 lines of code that’s doing the work inside the updateEmployeeButton, that’s not very complex. It’s all subjective. I will add that had I not posted anything, most people with answers would’ve passed on this question because it’s vague and no code added. It’s a starting point for the OP. Also note I wrote “There are several ways to do it”.

Comment: Oh - I totally agree. The OP question is vague at best and shows little to no research. My only point here is this answer doesn't remove a node or add a node, it just creates a entirely new node or overwrites what's there. Either way, if extrapolated out it's solid.